# conditional while loop(new to this community)

Tags: c++

I am new to this website.
I am a rookie and I am creating a simple game called pick a number with code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double number;
    char letter;
    char choice;
    while (number=true)

    {
        cout<<"enter a number from 0-10. no letters"<<endl;
        cin>>number;
        if (number==6){
            cout<<"you win"<<endl;
            system ("pause");}
        else if (number<0||number>10){
            cout<<"pick a number from the range given"<<endl;
            system ("pause");}
        else if (number!=6){
            cout<<"you lose"<<endl;
            system ("paeuse");}
        else if (letter!=6){
            cout<<"no letter. just a number"<<endl;
            system ("pause");}

        while (choice=true)
        {
            cout<<"would you like to play again? Y/y for yes, and N/n for no."<<endl;
            cin>>choice;
            if (choice=='Y','y'){
                cout<<"lets play again"<<endl;
                system ("pause");}
            else if (choice=='N','n'){
                cout<<"come again later"<<endl;
                system ("pause");
                return choice;}
            else if (choice!='Y','y','N','n'){
                cout<<"unknown. do you want to play?"<<endl;
                system ("pause");}
        }
    }
}
```

My goal:
1) I want to create a condition if the user inputs a letter, the system will prompt the user to select a number not a letter, and therefore the user will return to select a number again.

My problem:
1) After the game, I created 3 conditions whether the user wants to play again. As you see the code,

1. a) If I enter 'y' or 'Y', I will be directed to the game.
2. b) If i enter 'n' or 'N', the program will exit.
3. If i enter a letter
       that does not contain the 4 letters, the system will display the
       output you see, and I will have to answer the question again.

No matter what I entered, the second condition loop isn't working.

A help will be appreciated.

Comment: `choice=='Y','y'` should be `choice=='Y' || choice == 'y'`

Comment: typo: `"paeuse"`

Comment: unreachable code: `if (letter!=6)`

Comment: `while (number=true)` the simple `=` is suspicious, `==` would be UB as `number` is not initialized, but anyway types mismatch (even if conversion can apply).

Answer (score 1):

### Comparsion vs. assignment

The `=` operator is used for assignment. Therefore, `while(choice=true)` means:

- each iteration of the loop, set `choice` to `true`
- use the value of `choice` for the condition

The `==` operator is used for comparsion, for example `while(choice == true)`. This will do what you expect.

**However,** `== true` is redundant. Compare `Is the color of a banana being yellow a fact?` with `Is the color of a banana yellow?`. A more idiomatic way of saying this would be just `while(choice)`.

### `system`

The practice of using `system` is something many programmers are not a fan of, but this technically should work. The problem here is spelling: `paeuse` -> `pause`.

### Multiple choices

Unfortunately, this syntax does not do what you think it does:

```
if(a == 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

You need to specify each condition fully, like this:

```
if((a == 'b') || (a == 'c') || (a == 'd'))
```

Alternatively, you can use a switch:

```
switch(choice){
case 'Y':
case 'y':
    /* yes code */
    break;
case 'N':
case 'n':
    /* no code */
    break;
default:
    /* none of the above */
}
```

### When are the  loops supposed to end?

```
double number;
while(number == true){
```

What do you mean by that? It's like saying `Which is greater? A lightbulb or -7?` It doesn't make sense!

### `return`

`return` in your code ends the main loop and makes the value you pass to it the exit code of the program. This is probably nowhere near what you intended.

### Unassigned variable `letter`

Where do you use `letter`? It is only used to compare it against something, but since you didn't set it, it's Undefined Behavior.

### Turn on warnings in your compiler

They are your friends, not your enemy. You might not want to get more compiler errors, but if you turn them off, you will have to find the same problem the hard way.

### How I would write this

Please note that this is untested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main(){
    const int MIN = 0;  // avoid magic numbers
    const int MAX = 10;
    do {
        int secret = 4; // Chosen by a fair dice roll
                        // Guaranteed to be random ;)
                        // TODO: pseudo-random number generation
        int guess;

        while(true){        // this could've been done with a do..while,
                            // but it ended up increasing the complexity
            std::cout << "Enter a number from " << MIN
                      << " to " << MAX << std::endl;
            std::cin  >> guess;

            if(guess >= MIN && guess <= MAX){
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "The provided number is not in range, try again!\n";
        }

        if(secret == guess){
            std::cout << "Congratulations!";
        }else{
            std::cout << "Sorry, good luck next time!";
        }

        char choice;
        do {
            std::cout << " Play again? [Y/N] ";
            std::cin  >> choice;
            choice = std::tolower(choice); // convert uppercase to lowercase, don't touch the rest
            if(choice == 'n'){
                return;
            }else if(choice != 'y'){
                std::cout << "Y or N please."
            }
        }while(choice != 'y');
    }
}

Analyse this program. If you don't understand something, ask! I hope I made it clear.
```

Comment: I would have created sub functions.